# Azure Consumption API is very slow

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

Currently I am using Azure Consumption API for my program. But it is **very slow**, it takes almost **8 seconds to give the response**. What should I do now? Here is the azure API that I am using..

https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/subscriptionId/providers/Microsoft.Consumption/usageDetails?api-v

Here is the link to visit that API
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/consumption/usagedetails/list

Is there is any way to get the response faster from the Azure API??

Comment: You could limit the scope of the information you're asking for?

Comment: It is even slow in Azure Portal. Problem is that it is loading tremendeous amount of information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The amount of information it needs to collect, process and then present itself requires some time, and involve internal calls as well, that is why considering the server load and usage, it takes around 6 to 7 seconds sometimes even more. Taking into account the realtime nature of data, I think not much of information could have been cached, otherwise they would have done it already.